# Flutter - run a background task at a specific time of the day

Tags: flutter

I had been searching for ways to run a specif task at a specific time of the day in a Flutter app. I have come across [`android_alarm_manager`](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager) and some other packages but was not able to get this done effectively.
I am trying to **run a function at a particular time, say 12AM** to do some automation task.
How can I do this? Please help.

Thanks in advance.